# Jabx How do i form XML without child tags

Tags: jaxb

I have two objects like Vehicle and Car. Vehicle contains List of Cars. And Car contains carId, Name and Model number. Now I have to form an xml like below.

```
<Vehicle>
     <Car>Audi</Car> 
     <Car>BMW</Car>
     <Car>Chevrolet</Car>
</Vehicle>
```

My Class are like below

```
    public class Cars {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
}
```

and ...

```
    public class Vehicals {

    private List<Cars> cars;
}
```

With these objects we can form XML like below.

```
<Vehicle>
     <Car>
         <name>Audi</name>
      </Car> 
     <Car>
         <name>BMW</name>
     </Car>
     <Car>
         <name>Chevrolet</name>
     </Car>
</Vehicle>
```

But here i should not show name tag. I should get directly like `<car>Audi</Car>`. How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance
Tej.

Answer (score 1):

Use [@XmlValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlValue.html).

Try:

```
@XmlValue
private String name;
```

An `@XmlTransient` on other properties. See also [@XmlElementWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html).